# XML multiline to single line using VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I have an excel file. One of the cells include an XML script. I need to fetch the contents of this cell and paste them in a notepad. I am done with everything except I am unable to have the entire XML script in one single line. No white spaces after and before tags and no new line characters. Please assist. 
To maintain client data privacy, I have pasted below a sample XML script. This script is supposed to be in B7 cell of excel.

I cannot replace white spaces with nothing since I don't want the white spaces between attributes to be replaced with nothing.

P.S. I also tried using the Trim function, but that didn't work.

```
Range("B7").Value = Trim(Range("B7").Value)
```

XML Script -

```
<Tag1>
    <Tag2 xml version="1.0"/>
    <Tag3>
        <Tag4 name="Tag4">Hello</Tag4>
    </Tag3>
</Tag1>
```

Comment: So, you have XML string in one cell and you want to concatenate each line, in a single string, but keeping the spaces inside each line. Only the spaces at the start of each tag must be Trimmed. Is that understanding correct? If yes, I can provide a solution for your cell content, but, I suppose you have many such cells... Would you like to have one contigue string for each cell, or a big string for all the workbook?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. There is just one cell with this big XML string. I just want the leading and trailing whitespaces to be deleted and not the spaces in between attributes (For e.g. i would not want space between tag2 and xml to be deleted). But I would want the space between tag1 and tag2 be deleted and they be concatenated in one line

Comment: OK. I will post an answer for one cell case. Posted, but I can see you already marked the accepted answer...

Comment: @YasserKhalil  I am sorry if it seemed like that. I was only trying to explain. There was no bad attitude intended at all. I appreciate everyone trying to answer my questions.

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. I have introduced three different approaches. The second and the third are working exactly as you described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Function manyToOne(str As String)
    Do Until InStr(str, Chr(10) & " ") = 0
        str = Replace(str, Chr(10) & " ", Chr(10))
    Loop
    str = Replace(str, Chr(10), "")
    manyToOne = str
End Function
```

then you can call it from the sheet:

```
=manyToOne(A1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this function, please:

```
Function UniqueXMLStr(strXML) As String
  Dim arrXML As Variant, strUnique As String

   arrXML = Split(strXML, vbLf)
   strUnique = Join(arrXML, "")
   UniqueXMLStr = Replace(strUnique, "    ", "")
End Function
```

It can be tested using the next test Sub:

```
Sub testUnique()
    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = ActiveCell 'here you will have your example XML string
    Debug.Print UniqueXMLStr(cel.value) 'Here the unique string will be shown in Immediate Window (Ctrl + G in Visual Basic Editor)...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing Chr(10) with nothing

```
Sub Test()
Dim sInput As String
sInput = Range("A1").Value
sInput = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Replace(sInput, Chr(10), ""))
Debug.Print sInput
End Sub
```

Another approach to get rid of white spaces

```
Sub Test2()
Dim x, sOut As String, i As Long
x = Split(Range("A1").Value, Chr(10))
For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
    sOut = sOut & Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(x(i))
Next i
Debug.Print sOut
End Sub
```

Another approach using Regex

```
Sub Test_Using_Regex()
Dim sInput As String
sInput = Join(Split(Range("A1").Value, Chr(10)), "")
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = ">(\s*)<"
    If .Test(sInput) Then Debug.Print Replace(Trim(sInput), .Execute(sInput)(0).SubMatches(0), "") '.Replace(sInput, "$1")
End With
End Sub
```